# log4j 1.2 filter exception with ExpressionFilter

Tags: java, exception, filter, log4j

I'm using log4j1.2.17 and I want to filter some exception from my log and after trying a lot of staff I didn't got the result that I was expecting. Here is the Exception that I want to filter that normally will not be displayed in the log console:

```
2020-02-26 11:04:50,470 ERROR [worker #1] com.myPackage.myClass: Access denied
com.myPackage.myClass.model.RestException: Access denied
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

and here is my log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="file" value="log/myProject.log"/>
<param name="filePattern" value="/var/log/tomcat7/ideal-%i.log"/>
<param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
<param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="9"/>
<param name="Append" value="true"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n"/>
</layout>
      <!-- Exclude expected exceptions -->
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
    <param name="Expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= ' Access denied'"/>
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
</filter>
</appender>

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
<param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c: %m%n"/>
</layout>
    <!-- Exclude expected exceptions -->
<filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
    <param name="Expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= ' Access denied'"/>
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
</filter>
</appender>

<root>
<priority value="DEBUG" />
<___priority value="INFO" />
<appender-ref ref="file"/>
<appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I also tried 
`<param name="Expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= 'com.myPackage.myClass: Access denied'"/>`

```
<param name="Expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= 'com.myPackage.myClass.model.RestException: Access denied'"/>
```

but I still have the 'Access denied' Exception in my log

Comment: Did you manage to make `ExpressionFilter` work?

Comment: no I solved the problem using StringMatchFilter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after more research I changed the class filter 
from: "org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter" 
to: "org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter"
and it worked perfectly, now it hide that exception from my log

```
 <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
    <param name="StringToMatch" value="Access denied"/>
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
</filter>
```